# How Do I Reduce Top and Bottom Padding on Wordpress Code

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been trying to reduce padding top and bottom on this code but it seems not to work on CSS.

```
element.style {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.noo-vc-row {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 95px;
}
.noo-vc-row {
    position: relative;
}
.row, .noo-pricing-table {
    margin-left: -1.0714285714285714em;
    margin-right: -1.0714285714285714em;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
body {
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
body {
    color: #44494b;
```

When I reduce the padding to 80%, it works on inspect element but when I take it to CSS, it does not work. Please, help. Thanks.

Comment: Show the HTML part this CSS is applied to please.

Comment: Okay. I think to make it easier, here is the url https://workland.com.ng/home-job-2/. I want to close the gap that exists between Top Companies Recruiting this Month and Recent jobs/Top Jobs

Comment: Have you tried my below solution? Please, don't have me visit your site and figure things out. Cut and paste the HTML in your question, you can edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.style` in your browser console gives away that these styles come from HTML. In other words, the padding is hard coded in the HTML tags, probably as follows:

```
<div style='padding-top: 100px;padding-bottom: 100px;'></div>
```

Inline styles override external CSS. In order to override the inline style you need to add `!important` to your CSS, as follows:

```
#elementid {
    padding-top: 100px!important;
    padding-bottom: 100px!imporant;
}
```

Where `#elementid` is the ID of your element. Unfortunately you don't show the element you have selected...

Comment: Thanks guys

This worked

.noo-vc-row {
 padding-top: 1px !important;
 padding-bottom: 1px !important;
}